# how to multiple select data with sort data to new column (like AS Column) in one table..?

Tags: mysql, sql

how to multiple select & sort data to new column in one table .

Comment: Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-to-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557 and the accepted answer.

Comment: Have you read Gurwinder Singh's comment? Don't use images. Use text instead. Please edit your question, so others for whom images get blocked are able to read it, too.

Comment: I've downvoted the question as there is still only images instead of text, which makes this less useful for SO users.

Comment: Ok, sorry for that. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you want to aggregate your rows per timestring. Use conditional aggregation to get the separate values:

```
select
  sum(case when parameter = 'speed' then value end) as speed,
  sum(case when parameter = 'temperature' then value end) as temperature,
  sum(case when parameter = 'current' then value end) as current,
  sum(case when parameter = 'pressure' then value end) as pressure,
  timestring
from mixing
group by timestring;
```

(If it is not guaranteed to have just one record per timestring and parameter, then you'd have to decide for the appropriate aggregation, i.e. `SUM`, `AVG`, `MIN`, `MAX` etc., otherwise use any.)

Comment: Thorsten kettner, i tried your code but i have error with SQL.
notif is (SQL Error (1054): Unknown column 'value' in 'field list')
i tried your code in heidi SQL. 


exactly, i want to multiple select And i tried it with this code..! 
(select Value AS speed,TimeString from mixing where Parameter = 'speed' group by TimeString;)


but this code just show one column of speed, i want to show column temperature,current and pressure too,
but my code is wrong and fail to multiple select,
i tried it in heidi SQL.

Comment: Your picture shows a table named `mixed` with a column called `value`. So the error message `unknown column 'value'` makes no sense for above query. You must have made a mistake somewhere. Here is a working demo: http://rextester.com/UKPQ67861.

Comment: wow. yes your right.!! i'm mistake in uppercase at parameter and value type. i tried your code again and it worked. thank you very much @Thorsten Kettner